# Parse Error in C

Tags: c, parsing, syntax

I'm doing some bitwise operation homework and it says my code has a "parse error"
I'm assuming its the syntax or something...but I can't find a missing semi-colon or anything. 
Could you please spot why I might be getting the problem?

```
int isGreater(int x, int y)
{
      int xSign = (x>>31);
      int ySign = (y>>31);
      int check1 = (xSign & ySign) | (~xSign & ~ySign);
      int same = ( x + ((~y) + 1) )>>31;
      same = !(same & 0x1);
      int check2 = (check1 & same) | (~check1 & !xSign);
      int equal = (!(x ^ y))<<31>>31;
      return (equal & 0) | (~equal & check2);
}
```

Comment: Please post the full error message.

Comment: What's the exact error message, including the line number?

Comment: bits.c:294: parse error. Line 294 is the second to last line posted. I'm working in Unix, so it doesnt give me much specifics

Comment: Well, which line is 294?

Comment: the line is "int equal = (!(x ^ y))<<31>>31;" but I also heard that it could refer to the line before it

Comment: There are a number of things you could do more efficiently, but you have a real problem with this piece: `equal & 0`. It will always be zero.

Comment: Why is the `int equal =...` line like that? `!(x^y)` is either `0` or `1`, so `<< 31 >> 31` does nothing.

Comment: I realize that the (equal & 0) is redundant, should be either 0 or check2.  Either way, that still doesnt change my parse error

Comment: int equal is a mask that checks if x and y are equal. If they are; it returns all 1's

Comment: Funny enough, I rewrote the code line from line, and compiled it...no errors! I don't know why that would happen...user Kevin said that I could do some things more efficiently, I was wondering if you could point some of that out for me

Comment: What headers did you have?  Did one of them define a macro `equal`, such as `#define equal ==`?  One of the better ways to debug this would be to look at the output from the C pre-processor.  For example, `gcc -E bits.c`.  But you'd want to strip out as much code as you could (especially system headers) before using that.  Line 294 is a long way through the file...better if it was line 20.

Comment: There is no parse error in the code you posted (I just compiled it myself).  If the compiler is reporting a parse error inside your `isGreater` function, either it's a result of something preceding it, or the code you posted is somehow different from the code you compiled.

Answer (score 1):

There must be something fishy going on. Perhaps your editor clashed the `<<` or `>>` to some unicode character `«` or `»`.

Or the inverse you are writing `< <` or `> >` with a space somewhere. The parse then sees two distinct tokens e.g `<` and `<` instead of one `<<`.

Answer (score 0):

So, I wrote this little bit of code - it seems to do the exact same thing that yours does... I don't know if this helps or not, but it tells you which is greater, not if they're equal though. Not sure if it will help do anything but shorten your code.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int isGreater(int x, int y)
{
   return (y + (~x +1)) >> 31 & 1;
}

int main(void)
{
    int x = 1;
    int y = 2;
    int greater = isGreater(x,y);
    if(greater == 1) {
        printf("%i > %i \n", x, y);
    } else {
        printf("%i < %i \n", x, y);
    }
    return 0;
}
```